# Xcode UI test fails to edit multiple UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI with multiple `UITextField`s that I want to test by clearing their contents and typing new values. However, only the **first** field can be changed in a UI test; subsequent fields can be *cleared* (if their clear button is enabled), but they can't be typed into (using `XCUIElement.typeText()`), because the test `Failed to synthesize event: Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.` How can I edit multiple text fields in a given UI test function?

I've followed the advice in a couple of different UI testing questions:

- [Xcode UI Testing How to type text into custom class text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790781/xcode-ui-testing-how-to-type-text-into-custom-class-text-fields)
- [UI Test deleting text in text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821880/ui-test-deleting-text-in-text-field)
- [UI Testing Multiple UITextFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747562/ui-testing-multiple-uitextfields) - accessibility was disabled in one of the fields

The UI:

[image: App UI]

The `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!

    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
        let actionVC = UIAlertController(title: "You did it!",
                                         message: "\(field1.text ?? ""), \(field2.text ?? "")",
                                         preferredStyle: .alert)
        actionVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Awesome!", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(actionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The test:

```
class TextFieldTesterUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testReplaceTextInMultipleTextFields() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        let field1TextField = app.textFields["Field 1"]
        field1TextField.tap()
        app.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
        field1TextField.typeText("Oh")

        let field2TextField = app.textFields["Field 2"]
        field2TextField.tap()
        app.buttons["Clear text"].tap() // <-- 
        field2TextField.typeText("Susanna")

        app.staticTexts["Button"].tap()

        app.alerts["You did it!"].scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Awesome!"].tap()
    }

}
```

The error:

[image: Error message]
[I've posted this demonstration on GitHub.](https://github.com/PoikileCreations/TextFieldUITester)

Comment: Hi, I ran your GitHub Demo on an iOS 14.0.1 iPhone and an iOS 14.3 Simulator. In both cases the UI Tests succeeded flawlessly. Could it be an issue with iOS 14.5?

Comment: You're quite right--it works as intended in Xcode 13 beta 4 on an iOS 15.0 simulator. I wonder whether it's worth filing a bug report, since happens in the currently-shipping versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thisura Dodangoda pointed out, this code runs correctly on iOS 14.0.1 and 14.3, and I confirmed that it runs correctly on the 15.0 beta simulators. It appears to be a problem only on iOS 14.5, and perhaps on other versions between 14.3 and 15.0.